# MacBook Pro Late 2009 SATA slow/resets. Is my motherboard dying?

Tags: kernel, 10.10, macbook

My MacBook Pro runs slower the longer it's on. I am getting kernel warnings.

Some, but not all, resets correlate with AC power connects and disconnects.  I don't think the warnings do. (How do I tell?)

What are these errors? What causes them?

Can this damage the drive or corrupt data? What is it seeing that motivates these?

```
  02:37:16[    0.791992] ahci 0000:00:0b.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LSI0] -> GSI 20 (level, low) -> IRQ 20
  02:37:16[    0.792047] ahci 0000:00:0b.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
  02:37:16[    0.792053] ahci 0000:00:0b.0: controller can't do PMP, turning off CAP_PMP
  02:37:16[    0.792104] ahci 0000:00:0b.0: AHCI 0001.0200 32 slots 6 ports 1.5 Gbps 0x3 impl IDE mode
  02:37:16[    0.792107] ahci 0000:00:0b.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf pm led pio slum part boh 
  02:37:16[    0.792111] ahci 0000:00:0b.0: setting latency timer to 64
  02:37:16[    0.813473] scsi0 : ahci
  02:37:16[    0.823340] scsi1 : ahci
  02:37:16[    0.848164] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xe7484000 port 0xe7484100 irq 43
  02:37:16[    0.848166] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xe7484000 port 0xe7484180 irq 43
  02:37:16[    1.190132] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
  02:37:16[    1.190153] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
  02:37:16[    1.213568] ata1.00: ATA-8: OCZ-VERTEX2, 1.23, max UDMA/133
  02:37:16[    1.213572] ata1.00: 195371568 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
  02:37:16[    1.227293] ata2.00: ATA-8: ST9500420ASG, 0002SDM1, max UDMA/133
  02:37:16[    1.227297] ata2.00: 976773168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
  02:37:16[    1.229570] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:37:16[    1.240120] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5850000 action 0xe frozen
  02:37:16[    1.240123] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:37:16[    1.240127] ata2: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:37:16[    1.240133] ata2: hard resetting link
  02:37:16[    1.260738] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:37:16[    1.280111] ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5850000 action 0xe frozen
  02:37:16[    1.280114] ata1: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:37:16[    1.280118] ata1: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:37:16[    1.280122] ata1: hard resetting link
  02:37:16[    1.990101] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
  02:37:16[    1.994215] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:37:16[    1.994220] ata2: EH complete
  02:37:16[    2.030097] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
  02:37:16[    2.090773] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:37:16[    2.090778] ata1: EH complete
  02:37:16[    2.090931] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      OCZ-VERTEX2      1.23 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
  02:37:16[    2.091045] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
  02:37:16[    2.091121] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 195371568 512-byte logical blocks: (100 GB/93.1 GiB)
  02:37:16[    2.091159] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST9500420ASG     0002 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
  02:37:16[    2.091163] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
  02:37:16[    2.091165] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
  02:37:16[    2.091183] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
  02:37:16[    2.091252] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
  02:37:16[    2.091446] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
  02:37:16[    2.091580] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
  02:37:16[    2.091582] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
  02:37:16[    2.091637] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
  02:37:16[    2.093140] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
  02:37:16[    2.093773] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
  02:37:16[    2.693899] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
  02:37:16[    5.483492] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
  02:37:16[    7.905040] EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
  02:37:25[   19.553095] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=600
  02:37:25[   19.555266] EXT4-fs (dm-2): re-mounted. Opts: commit=600
  02:37:25[   19.641532] ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5950000 action 0xe frozen t4
  02:37:25[   19.641532] ata1: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:37:25[   19.641532] ata1: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake Dispar LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:37:25[   19.641533] ata1: hard resetting link
  02:37:25[   19.642076] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5950000 action 0xe frozen t4
  02:37:25[   19.642078] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:37:25[   19.642081] ata2: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake Dispar LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:37:25[   19.642084] ata2: hard resetting link
  02:37:26[   20.392606] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
  02:37:26[   20.392610] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
  02:37:26[   20.396697] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:37:26[   20.396703] ata2: EH complete
  02:37:26[   20.451491] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:37:26[   20.451498] ata1: EH complete
  02:37:30[   24.563725] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=600
  02:37:30[   24.565939] EXT4-fs (dm-2): re-mounted. Opts: commit=600
  02:37:30[   24.627236] ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5900000 action 0xe frozen t4
  02:37:30[   24.627240] ata1: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:37:30[   24.627242] ata1: SError: { Dispar LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:37:30[   24.627246] ata1: hard resetting link
  02:37:30[   24.632241] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5950000 action 0xe frozen t4
  02:37:30[   24.632244] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:37:30[   24.632247] ata2: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake Dispar LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:37:30[   24.632250] ata2: hard resetting link
  02:37:31[   25.372582] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
  02:37:31[   25.382615] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
  02:37:31[   25.386782] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:37:31[   25.386788] ata2: EH complete
  02:37:31[   25.431668] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:37:31[   25.431674] ata1: EH complete
  02:45:54[  529.141844] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=0
  02:45:55[  529.544529] EXT4-fs (dm-2): re-mounted. Opts: commit=0
  02:45:55[  529.622561] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
  02:45:55[  529.622568] ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5850000 action 0xe frozen
  02:45:55[  529.622572] ata1: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
  02:45:55[  529.622576] ata1: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:45:55[  529.622583] ata1: hard resetting link
  02:45:55[  529.622609] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
  02:45:55[  529.622613] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5950000 action 0xe frozen
  02:45:55[  529.622616] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:45:55[  529.622620] ata2: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake Dispar LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:45:55[  529.622624] ata2: hard resetting link
  02:45:56[  530.380135] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:45:56[  530.380157] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:45:56[  530.384305] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:45:56[  530.384314] ata2: EH complete
  02:45:56[  530.399225] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:45:56[  530.399233] ata1: EH complete
  02:45:58[  532.395990] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=600
  02:45:58[  532.518270] EXT4-fs (dm-2): re-mounted. Opts: commit=600
  02:45:58[  532.590968] ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5840000 action 0xe frozen t4
  02:45:58[  532.590973] ata1: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:45:58[  532.590977] ata1: SError: { CommWake LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:45:58[  532.590983] ata1: hard resetting link
  02:45:58[  532.591034] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5950000 action 0xe frozen t4
  02:45:58[  532.591037] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:45:58[  532.591041] ata2: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake Dispar LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:45:58[  532.591045] ata2: hard resetting link
  02:45:59[  533.340147] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:45:59[  533.340168] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:45:59[  533.344416] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:45:59[  533.344424] ata2: EH complete
  02:45:59[  533.360839] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:45:59[  533.360847] ata1: EH complete
  02:45:59[  533.584449] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=0
  02:45:59[  533.586999] EXT4-fs (dm-2): re-mounted. Opts: commit=0
  02:45:59[  533.660117] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5950000 action 0xe frozen
  02:45:59[  533.660122] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:45:59[  533.660126] ata2: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake Dispar LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:45:59[  533.660132] ata2: hard resetting link
  02:45:59[  533.660141] ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5850000 action 0xe frozen
  02:45:59[  533.660143] ata1: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:45:59[  533.660147] ata1: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:45:59[  533.660151] ata1: hard resetting link
  02:46:00[  534.412536] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:46:00[  534.412562] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:46:00[  534.416768] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:46:00[  534.416777] ata2: EH complete
  02:46:00[  534.431396] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:46:00[  534.431401] ata1: EH complete
  02:46:03[  537.384649] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=600
  02:46:03[  537.504214] EXT4-fs (dm-2): re-mounted. Opts: commit=600
  02:46:03[  537.585992] ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5900000 action 0xe frozen t4
  02:46:03[  537.585996] ata1: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:46:03[  537.585999] ata1: SError: { Dispar LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:46:03[  537.586002] ata1: hard resetting link
  02:46:03[  537.586028] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5950000 action 0xe frozen t4
  02:46:03[  537.586030] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:46:03[  537.586033] ata2: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake Dispar LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:46:03[  537.586036] ata2: hard resetting link
  02:46:04[  538.330147] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:46:04[  538.330168] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:46:04[  538.334389] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:46:04[  538.334398] ata2: EH complete
  02:46:04[  538.343511] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
  02:46:04[  538.343519] ata1: EH complete
  02:46:04[  538.456413] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=0
  02:46:04[  538.459404] EXT4-fs (dm-2): re-mounted. Opts: commit=0
  02:46:04[  538.540138] ata1.00: limiting speed to UDMA/100:PIO4
  02:46:04[  538.540144] ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5850000 action 0xe frozen
  02:46:04[  538.540148] ata1: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:46:04[  538.540153] ata1: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:46:04[  538.540159] ata1: hard resetting link
  02:46:04[  538.540202] ata2.00: limiting speed to UDMA/100:PIO4
  02:46:04[  538.540207] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5950000 action 0xe frozen
  02:46:04[  538.540211] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:46:04[  538.540215] ata2: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake Dispar LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:46:04[  538.540220] ata2: hard resetting link
  02:46:05[  539.290054] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:46:05[  539.290041] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:46:05[  539.294100] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
  02:46:05[  539.294106] ata2: EH complete
  02:46:05[  539.314125] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
  02:46:05[  539.314132] ------------[ cut here ]------------
  02:46:05[  539.314140] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-2.6.35/drivers/ata/libata-eh.c:3638 ata_eh_finish+0xdf/0xf0()
  02:46:05[  539.314144] Hardware name: MacBookPro5,3
  02:46:05[  539.314146] Modules linked in: michael_mic arc4 xt_multiport binfmt_misc rfcomm sco bnep l2cap parport_pc ppdev nvidia(P) ipt_REJECT xt_recent snd_hda_codec_cirrus xt_limit xt_tcpudp ipt_addrtype xt_state snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi applesmc led_class ip6table_filter lib80211_crypt_tkip snd_rawmidi snd_seq_midi_event ip6_tables input_polldev hid_apple snd_seq wl(P) snd_timer snd_seq_device snd joydev bcm5974 usbhid mbp_nvidia_bl uvcvideo btusb videodev v4l1_compat v4l2_compat_ioctl32 nf_nat_irc hid nf_conntrack_irc soundcore snd_page_alloc i2c_nforce2 coretemp lib80211 bluetooth nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack lp parport iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables usb_storage firewire_ohci firewire_core forcedeth crc_itu_t ahci libahci
  02:46:05[  539.314221] Pid: 202, comm: scsi_eh_0 Tainted: P            2.6.35-25-generic #44-Ubuntu
  02:46:05[  539.314224] Call Trace:
  02:46:05[  539.314233]  [<ffffffff8106091f>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7f/0xc0
  02:46:05[  539.314237]  [<ffffffff8106097a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
  02:46:05[  539.314242]  [<ffffffff813dc77f>] ata_eh_finish+0xdf/0xf0
  02:46:05[  539.314246]  [<ffffffff813e441e>] sata_pmp_error_handler+0x2e/0x40
  02:46:05[  539.314256]  [<ffffffffa00021bf>] ahci_error_handler+0x1f/0x90 [libahci]
  02:46:05[  539.314261]  [<ffffffff813dd6d2>] ata_scsi_error+0x492/0x5e0
  02:46:05[  539.314266]  [<ffffffff813b24cd>] scsi_error_handler+0x10d/0x190
  02:46:05[  539.314270]  [<ffffffff813b23c0>] ? scsi_error_handler+0x0/0x190
  02:46:05[  539.314275]  [<ffffffff8107f266>] kthread+0x96/0xa0
  02:46:05[  539.314280]  [<ffffffff8100aee4>] kernel_thread_helper+0x4/0x10
  02:46:05[  539.314284]  [<ffffffff8107f1d0>] ? kthread+0x0/0xa0
  02:46:05[  539.314288]  [<ffffffff8100aee0>] ? kernel_thread_helper+0x0/0x10
  02:46:05[  539.314291] ---[ end trace 76dbffc2d5d49d9b ]---
  02:46:05[  539.314296] ata1: EH complete
  02:46:12[  547.040091] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
  02:46:12[  547.040098] ata1.00: failed command: IDENTIFY DEVICE
  02:46:12[  547.040106] ata1.00: cmd ec/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0 pio 512 in
  02:46:12[  547.040108]          res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
  02:46:12[  547.040111] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
  02:46:12[  547.040117] ata1: hard resetting link
  02:46:13[  547.390144] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:46:13[  547.408430] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
  02:46:13[  547.408438] ------------[ cut here ]------------
  02:46:13[  547.408447] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-2.6.35/drivers/ata/libata-eh.c:3638 ata_eh_finish+0xdf/0xf0()
  02:46:13[  547.408451] Hardware name: MacBookPro5,3
  02:46:13[  547.408453] Modules linked in: michael_mic arc4 xt_multiport binfmt_misc rfcomm sco bnep l2cap parport_pc ppdev nvidia(P) ipt_REJECT xt_recent snd_hda_codec_cirrus xt_limit xt_tcpudp ipt_addrtype xt_state snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi applesmc led_class ip6table_filter lib80211_crypt_tkip snd_rawmidi snd_seq_midi_event ip6_tables input_polldev hid_apple snd_seq wl(P) snd_timer snd_seq_device snd joydev bcm5974 usbhid mbp_nvidia_bl uvcvideo btusb videodev v4l1_compat v4l2_compat_ioctl32 nf_nat_irc hid nf_conntrack_irc soundcore snd_page_alloc i2c_nforce2 coretemp lib80211 bluetooth nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack lp parport iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables usb_storage firewire_ohci firewire_core forcedeth crc_itu_t ahci libahci
  02:46:13[  547.408528] Pid: 202, comm: scsi_eh_0 Tainted: P        W   2.6.35-25-generic #44-Ubuntu
  02:46:13[  547.408531] Call Trace:
  02:46:13[  547.408540]  [<ffffffff8106091f>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7f/0xc0
  02:46:13[  547.408544]  [<ffffffff8106097a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
  02:46:13[  547.408549]  [<ffffffff813dc77f>] ata_eh_finish+0xdf/0xf0
  02:46:13[  547.408553]  [<ffffffff813e441e>] sata_pmp_error_handler+0x2e/0x40
  02:46:13[  547.408563]  [<ffffffffa00021bf>] ahci_error_handler+0x1f/0x90 [libahci]
  02:46:13[  547.408567]  [<ffffffff813dd6d2>] ata_scsi_error+0x492/0x5e0
  02:46:13[  547.408572]  [<ffffffff813b24cd>] scsi_error_handler+0x10d/0x190
  02:46:13[  547.408577]  [<ffffffff813b23c0>] ? scsi_error_handler+0x0/0x190
  02:46:13[  547.408582]  [<ffffffff8107f266>] kthread+0x96/0xa0
  02:46:13[  547.408587]  [<ffffffff8100aee4>] kernel_thread_helper+0x4/0x10
  02:46:13[  547.408591]  [<ffffffff8107f1d0>] ? kthread+0x0/0xa0
  02:46:13[  547.408595]  [<ffffffff8100aee0>] ? kernel_thread_helper+0x0/0x10
  02:46:13[  547.408598] ---[ end trace 76dbffc2d5d49d9c ]---
  02:46:13[  547.408620] ata1: EH complete
  02:46:13[  547.562470] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=600
  02:46:13[  547.671380] EXT4-fs (dm-2): re-mounted. Opts: commit=600
  02:46:13[  547.738198] ata1.00: limiting speed to UDMA/33:PIO4
  02:46:13[  547.738204] ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5800000 action 0xe frozen t4
  02:46:13[  547.738208] ata1: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:46:13[  547.738212] ata1: SError: { LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:46:13[  547.738218] ata1: hard resetting link
  02:46:13[  547.738262] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5900000 action 0xe frozen t4
  02:46:13[  547.738265] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:46:13[  547.738269] ata2: SError: { Dispar LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:46:13[  547.738274] ata2: hard resetting link
  02:46:14[  548.482561] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:46:14[  548.484083] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:46:14[  548.486809] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
  02:46:14[  548.486818] ata2: EH complete
  02:46:14[  548.498998] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
  02:46:14[  548.499004] ata1: EH complete
  02:46:18[  552.410499] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=600
  02:46:18[  552.522521] EXT4-fs (dm-2): re-mounted. Opts: commit=600
  02:46:18[  552.529674] ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5800000 action 0xe frozen t4
  02:46:18[  552.529678] ata1: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:46:18[  552.529680] ata1: SError: { LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:46:18[  552.529684] ata1: hard resetting link
  02:46:18[  552.529716] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5800000 action 0xe frozen t4
  02:46:18[  552.529718] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
  02:46:18[  552.529720] ata2: SError: { LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
  02:46:18[  552.529723] ata2: hard resetting link
  02:46:19[  553.280059] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:46:19[  553.280068] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
  02:46:19[  553.284141] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
  02:46:19[  553.284150] ata2: EH complete
  02:46:19[  553.301629] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
  02:46:19[  553.301637] ata1: EH complete
```

Answer (score 1):

This look like it might be the cause: https://bugs.launchpad.net/linux/+bug/576601

I see you have not installed the Apple EFI firmware update 1.7 that is known to cause bus errors that can corrupt data due to faulty SATA2 3Gps support that the update turns on.  That rules that out.  Or perhaps your chipset is even worse than the average?

Does anyone have a log of what the kernel errors look like for either the nvidia interrupt handling (supposedly fixed for a MBP7,1, though perhaps not yours) or faulty SATA bugs?

Comment: and/or https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/610055

Comment: The first URL claims its fixed.  The second seems unclear.  What's the fix?

Comment: The original link seems to be for an old kernel bug that was patched long before 10.10 was released.